# Disable Foreign Key Constraint Code First EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

If I wanted to disable foreign key constraint on a relationship. I would do the following if I was editing in database:

[image]

But I want the disabling of a foreign key constraint on a relationship in my **migration file** or in my **configuration** or in my **model** in the form of annotation in respect to 'Code First' approach. So far I came up with nothing but I tried with `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` though. I also noticed that EF does not care if I take the liberty of disabling foreign key constraint from database but that would violate code first approach in my perspective. 
So, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution I found was to run my own custom migration like :

`Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.ProductItems NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ProductItems_dbo.Services_ProductItemTypeId]");`

Do not know whether that is the only way. Still open to suggestions.

Comment: Did this actually work for you? I tried it and the constraint is still in effect when I try to drop the primary key of the principal table. I had to drop the FK first. The FK has cascade delete in my case, if that is relevant.